# LINQ and converting int? to int

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Following gives me a cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) error:

```
public class JobStructure
{
    public JobStructure()
    {
    }
    public JobStructure(int? jobId, int? parentJobId)
    {
        var js = from r in dbc.fnJobStructure(someParameter_to_database_function)
                 select new JobStructure
                 {
                    JobID = r.JobID //<-------------ERROR: cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
                 };
    }
    public int JobID { get; set; }
}
```

JobID is of type Int, and r.JobId that's coming from my database is nullable (it shouldn't be but it is). That's beyond the point;

I just wanna know how to deal with this problem int? to int problem in general

thanks

---

### EDIT

Actually, Never mind;
I don't have a way of verifying the answers; the problem here is a fundamental one; I'm creating a whole new instance of my class inside the linq expression which will have its own JobId; 
so when I'm actually calling the JobStructure constructor, I am never assigning a proper jobId (a new instance in the linq gets created and once we're out of the constructor, that instance with the proper jobId is dead.)
Anyways thought I'd let everyone know (I tried to delete my question, but it warned against it... so I'm leaving it here with the Edited note)
cheers

Comment: The compiler is telling you what you need to do - you need convert `int?` to `int`, e.g. `JobID = r.JobID.Value`. The real question is what do you want to do when `r.JobID` is `null`?

Comment: How do you want to deal with records which do have `r.JobID` as `null`?

Comment: This is just an example (and I know for a fact jobID will never ever be null; don't wanna get into it). There's a very nice way of handling this (LINQ gets translated into a proper SQL query;) I just don't remember what the trick was to do this conversion... It was always on top of my google searches... I just can't find it anymore.

Comment: Some notes, despite your edit. If you know for sure that `r.JobID` is never null, you can simply use `r.JobID.Value`. For the rest I wonder what you're trying to achieve by the code you show. Maybe you can focus on that if you want support in that area and so salvage your question.

Comment: _"I tried to delete my question, but it warned against it"_ I deleted my upvoted answer. Check if you can delete the question now.

Comment: @AlexD, thanks for the reply. in LINQ queries you cannot use r.jobID.Value unfortunately; this is a LINQ query against a DataEntity Model; so the LINQ Query is translated to a SQL statement at run time; I think VS doesn't have a way of translating r.jobId.value into ISNULL(jobID, ???) or coalesce(jobId, ???); so r.jobID.value actually fails at runtime :(

Answer (score 1):

JobID  is not nullable so if your r.JobID will be null then it will not accept because JobID is not null able so better to use Zero(0) in case of null

```
JobID = r.JobID ?? 0;
```

or simply change JobID to nullable

```
 public int? JobID { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks for your replay; unfortunately int? JobID{get;set;} is bending the rules; the reality is, JobID is not nullable; it's a shortcoming of DataEntityModel when using Function Driven data; 1. in the Table definition, JobID in the Database is a PK. 2. In the function from which I generate my EntityModel, JobID always has a value (due to an 'inner join' condition, or I won't have a row); Unfortunately Data Entity Model doesn't dig that deep to determine if a field is nullable or not when coming from a SQL-Function (quite understandably so, of course)

Comment: If you are sure than you will always have value then user the first option r.JobID?? 0; and second part will never execute.

Comment: I tried that; I'm not sure how to confirm if that works though; You see in my example, I'm creating a "new jobStructure" in that Linq query; the problem is I was trying to set "this" to it; so I ended up getting the list from the LINQ and parsing it out into the instance... I think/hope r.jobID??0 approach will work in other situations; I just do remember there are certain c-sharpy things we can't incorporate into LINQy queries.... thanks for the follow up on this though :)